# How to add Roman numbering on Section and subsection?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am writing paper using IEEE template and have encountered trouble with adding number at the front of section and subsection. I tried using renewcommand but it doesn't work. This is my current code

```
\documentclass{IEEEcsmag}

\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{upmath}


\jvol{XX}
\jnum{XX}
\paper{8}
\jmonth{May/June}
\jname{IT Professional}
\pubyear{2019}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Add Reference style
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=ieee,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}

% Add Reference source 
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
```

This is the link for upmath.sty and IEEECSmag.cls [files](https://www.transfernow.net/QfObIn092020). I get this part directly from the template and I haven't changed it.

I want to use roman style numbering on each of the section and subsection. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Roman numbering for both sections and subsections? This is very confusional. Roman for sections and roman for subsections at a pinch. Or Roman and greek respectively.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. So I want I,II,III for the section and 1.1,1.2,1.3 for the subsection

Comment: Not `I.1`, &c.?

Comment: Nah. Just like I mention before

Comment: Wher doe the IEEEcsmag class and the upmath package come from?

Comment: There is another file for it. I have updated my questions with links to it if you want since there is too much word on it